# Seaborn Heatmap Changing Text Size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to make array values bigger and more readable on the confusion matrix. When I set seaborn text size, everything gets bigger title, x and y axis titles etc. How can I just make confusion matrix values bigger? Here is the code below.

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array = [[1779, 17, 6, 2, 1], 
        [7, 348, 15, 0, 0], 
        [11, 29, 930, 13, 16], 
        [0, 0, 24, 160, 9], 
        [1, 5, 20, 13, 256]
        ]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = ['No DR', 'Mild', 'Moderate', 'Severe', 'Proliferative' ],
                  columns = ['No DR', 'Mild', 'Moderate', 'Severe', 'Proliferative' ])

plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
hmap = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt='g', cmap="Blues")

plt.title('VGG16 Base Model', fontsize = 20, pad=20)
plt.xlabel('Predicted Class', fontsize = 15, labelpad=20) 
plt.ylabel('Actual Class', fontsize = 15, labelpad=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. Changing the heatmap line:

```
hmap = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt='g', cmap="Blues", annot_kws={'size': 15})
```

results as I want.